# DS1620 in SMT format has different output than the dip version

Tags: surface-mount, temperature

I'm polling a DS1620 and converting the raw data to degrees F and it works fine using the dip 8-pin chip. I bought some SMT chips and soldered them to adapter boards and tested them using the same sw/hw and I get a different range of raw values. The values that are supposed to be returned are in 1/2 degree C from -66F to 257F and the raw values are 403->511 (-66F->31.1F) and 0->250 (32.0F->257F) but I tested the SMT version using an ice bath and I got it to go as low as 408 and then put a space heater under it and got it up to 492. I looked over several data sheets for the DS1620 and tried googling it and the only thing I can figure is it's some cheap Chinese knock-off. I guess I'll have to just put the dip version next to the SMT version and make a note of the temps for each and just interpolate.

Comment: Hmm. What if the upper bit is stuck as '1' (or reading as such)? Would that explain observation?

Comment: It returned 408 in an ice bath: 408=198h -> 98h = 152 -> 152/2 = 76 if measured in 1/2 degrees would seem kinda high even for F.

Comment: I tried bit reversing the values 408 and 492 and that doesn't sound right either.

Comment: Okay. I was just curious if that might have been the issue. It appears not. Thanks for checking. :)